# VSTS build triggered twice with each push

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, build-chain

I have a chained 2 builds scenario setup in VSTS.

I have a CI build, called '*Sync VSTS to GitHub*' which runs two steps:

1. A powershell command which pushes the changes from that commit to GitHub.
2. Trigger another build, which compiles the solution, runs tests, deployments etc.  (lets call it '*Proper Build*')

This *Sync VSTS to GitHub* build **has a trigger which detects when a push** was made.
That executes all OK.

The second build, the '*Proper Build*' **has no CI triggers defined**. It is only supposed to be triggered manually (or rather by the 'Sync VSTS to GitHub' build).

What happens is that every time a push is made in Visual Studio, the '*Sync VSTS to GitHub*' build is called. That succeeds, and then calls the *Proper Build*. And for some reason, this build is queued twice for the same changeset! 
This second build is added after the first one runs for a short while:

[image]

Suddenly a wild build appears:
[image]

The only difference that I see between the builds is the user on behalf of which the build is triggered:

First Build:
[image]

Second Build:
[image]

What is particularly weird is that **this does not happen when the build is queued manually from VSTS** (without a new changeset). In such scenario, each build is triggered once.

The build task that triggers the *Proper Build* is this one:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks

This is how I configure it (I tried setting the highlighted option to different value, no effect).
[image]

To confirm - when this task is **disabled**, then the '*Proper Build*' is **not triggered at all** (as expected)

Any idea how to avoid this duplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer is actually simple:

1. Get rid of the 'trigger build' task
2. Create a Build Completion trigger on the 'Proper Build' as below:

[image]

That's it!

Comment: You can accept the answer. And it will also benefit others who meet the similar questions.